# Firemonkey app. needs data updates

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have a client database iPad/Iphone iOS application running OK.  I wish to be able to easily update the data associated with the application and the ideal solution would be to read from a text file on my PC when I am connected to iTunes on my (Windows XP) PC.

Can my iPhone/iPad app open a file on my PC when connected to iTunes?  I can't get a file path specification that will work (allow me to open a file on my PC).

I have also investigated the iTunes FILE SHARING facility, requires a manual modification to the application .PLIST file to turn this on.  Since whenever I rebuild and "Export to XCode" my application a new .PLIST file is generated I have to manualy edit it each time to get the file sharing changes made so this seems to not be the answer.

Alternatively packaging the file with the iOS application would be workable. I get some sort of application checksum error if I drop the data file into the xCode application.. not sure why.  I understood this was the mechanism to get the data file packaged with the project.  Maybe I am dropping the data file in the wrong place...

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the actual question? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the menu item Deployment under the Project drop down menu in XE2 does the job.  Allows files, images etc to be packaged up with the application.